# Navigation menu not working in admin panel of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menubar

My Wordpress menu bar is not working. i am creating a new menu but when i add some pages or categories into the menu it does not get reorder. Please help to sort it out I am using the woo-commerce in which it has given me inbuilt menus that is not getting reorder.

Comment: are you saying that new items you put in the menu aren't getting ordered in the way you want them to be ordered?

Comment: Hi Viking, Not just new items but also the already containing items are not get reorder in the menu into wp-admin of wordpress

Comment: is the order staying static no matter what you try to rearrange?

Answer (score 0):

I got this bug. this was because of the plugins.
i had installed
1. Rich Tax Description Editor
2. Turns Description field on Taxonomy pages into the full scale Rich Text Editor.
3. Rich Text Widget

That was creating problem in menu. when i deactivated them all i got it back. my menu ordering was working fine.